# console command from ruby not work

Tags: ruby, linux, macos

i clone github repo

```
https://github.com/DeNADev/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL
```

and than to pre compile shall run

```
./autogen.sh
```

from console it work, log:

```
Searching libtoolize...
-e  FOUND: libtoolize -> glibtoolize
...
```

but if i do it from ruby script like

```
  system "git clone https://github.com/DeNADev/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL.git handlersocket-plugin"
  Dir.chdir("handlersocket-plugin") do
    system "./autogen.sh"
  end
```

log:

```
./autogen.sh 
Searching libtoolize...
-e  WARNING: Cannot Found libtoolize... input libtool command
...
```

how can i fix it?

work on Mac OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your environment variables, especially `PATH`
from shell:

```
env
```

from ruby:

```
p ENV
```